# How to add file upload section in the admin product view page?

Tags: product, customer, product-detail-page, download, special-character

I am trying to add file upload section in admin product view page.
Because I want to display to customer the product specification download in the frontend product detail page.
Please tell me example code or consideration.

Comment: Kindly refer to the provided link for instructions on creating a custom attribute and displaying it on the product page. [https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-attach-a-file-in-product-admin-form-and-display-attachment-in-product-detail-page-in-magento-2/](https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-attach-a-file-in-product-admin-form-and-display-attachment-in-product-detail-page-in-magento-2/) I hope this information is helpful. If you have any other questions or concerns, please let me know. Thanks